# if/else column value choose select table, exclude null in json

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

use this query get json result like below data structure,

```
SELECT c.* ,
    row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery, 
    row_to_json(m.*) as media,
    row_to_json(g.*) as gallery
  FROM comment c

  LEFT JOIN media m ON m.id = c.endpoint_id
  .... join mg g table
```

is it possible base on column value choose select table maybe like this syntax ,  exclude the media_gallery, media and gallery in result if is null

```
SELECT c.* ,
  CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 1
  THEN
    row_to_json(mg.*) as media_gallery, 
    row_to_json(m.*) as media,
  END

  CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 0 THEN
    row_to_json(g.*) as gallery
  END

  FROM comment c

  LEFT JOIN media m ON m.id = c.endpoint_id
  .... join mg g table
```

result

```
  rows: 
[ { id: 7,
  endpoint_code: 0,
  endpoint_id: 27,
  status: 0,

  media_gallery: null,
  media: null,
  gallery: 
   { id: 27,
     status: 0,
     create_date: 
   ...
```

UPDATE

I also tried this, but not work

```
COALESCE( row_to_json(mg.*), null) AS media_gallery,
```

Comment: A `case` statement only returns a **single** expression.

Comment: A case expression...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for reply , I just don't get it :(  .  I update my code base on below Gordon Linoff answer ,  but still return result contain media_gallery, media or gallery, nothing change use case or not ... do you know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you intend?

```
SELECT c.* ,
       (CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 1 THEN row_to_json(mg.*) END) as media_gallery,
       (CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 1 THEN row_to_json(m.*) END) as media,
       (CASE WHEN c.endpoint_code = 0 THEN row_to_json(g.*) END) as gallery
.  . .
```

Comment: thanks for reply I try this, but seems nothing different with not use case, it still return result like `media_gallery: null,
 media: null,
 gallery: 
 { id: 27,
 status: 0,` I want only return gallery or media_gallery, media ...